# How to add no internet connection page in my web view application?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to add a no internet connection page to my webview application but I can't. I am not much experienced on it just I am creating this application by following some youtube videos. I have added progressbar, swiprefresh, exit dialogue popup and want to add no internet connection page too along with these. I have attached my code below -Kindly help me please!

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_Bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:progress="20"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_internet"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/noInternet"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Internet Connection"
        android:layout_below="@+id/noInternet"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtNoConnection"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:text="Retry"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNoConnection"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNoInternet"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
private String webUrl="http://godigitalzone.in/";
ProgressBar progressBar;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
Button btnNoInternet;
Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipe = findViewById(R.id.swipe);

    webView=findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
    progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress_Bar);
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");

    btnNoInternet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNoInternet);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    webView.loadUrl(webUrl);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    checkConnection();
    

    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressDialog.show();
            if (newProgress==100){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);;
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to Exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
public void checkConnection(){

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
   NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

   if (wifi.isConnected()){

       webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   }
   else if (mobile.isConnected()){
       webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   else {
       webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used the following in my projects:

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


public class DetectConnection {             
  public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {   

    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
      context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
  }
}

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


public class DetectConnection {             
  public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {   

    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
      context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
        && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
  }
}

if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {      
  wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.donate_webView1);
  c = new CustomWebViewClient();
  wv.setWebViewClient(c);
  wv.clearCache(true);
  wv.clearHistory();
  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
  wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}


// Function to load all URLs in same webview
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }     
    return true;
  }
}

Update the Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```